# Android Debug Bridge (adb) backup/restore

Tags: adb, backup

I'm a bit confused with output bellow and was hoping someone can help me to decipher it for me)

```
backup/restore:
 backup [-f FILE] [-apk|-noapk] [-obb|-noobb] [-shared|-noshared] [-all] [-system|-nosystem] [PACKAGE...]
     write an archive of the device's data to FILE [default=backup.adb]
     package list optional if -all/-shared are supplied
     -apk/-noapk: do/don't back up .apk files (default -noapk)
     -obb/-noobb: do/don't back up .obb files (default -noobb)
     -shared|-noshared: do/don't back up shared storage (default -noshared)
     -all: back up all installed applications
     -system|-nosystem: include system apps in -all (default -system)
 restore FILE             restore device contents from FILE
```

My goal is very simple here; I'm about to perform factory reset and would like to take a backup of my phone, so I can restore my phone as it is now (before factory reset) (what is `.obb` files??)

Would following help me accomplish my goal or do I need something else like `-all`?

> adb backup -f 05102017 -shared -nosystem

Please advise.

Comment: Just for curiosity: what good is a factory reset when doing a full restore afterwards, bringing everything back (except the things that backup doesn't cover, like SMS)? From a full backup you only can do a full restore (except for some tricks you only can do with root). So wouldn't you rather prefer separate backup packages for a selective restore? If so, you might wish to take a look at my tool [Adebar](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar), which a.o. would generate the necessary scripts for that. And: `.obb` is [Opaque Binary Blob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_binary_blob).

Comment: @Izzy my boot-loader is unlocked, and I want to re-lock it and in order for that to happen, factory reset would be performed cleaning up my phone and I'd like to get back to same state as I am now (just with locked boot-loader), I wish to use native tools *only*, such as `adb`.

Comment: AFAIK a factory-reset is only performed on *unlocking* the bootloader (as otherwise an unauthorized could gain access to your data that way), but not on re-locking it. OK, got the idea – never wrong to have a backup, especially before operations like that :) PS: Note that such a backup would include SD card contents as well (which then also would be restored), so the archive can get quite big.

Comment: @Izzy, that's not true as of now factory reset is required on re-locking as well. I don't have `/sdcard` in my phone (only internal memory).

Comment: First time I hear that – but thanks for the detail. They always invent new craziness… What does "as of now" refer to? A specific device, or a specific Android version?

Comment: @Izzy My device Nexus 6p w/ Android 7.1.2.

Comment: OK, so it is "N" specific (either Nexus or Nougat or both)…

Comment: @Izzy Maybe Nexus 6p specific? as I do remember having same thing with Android M as well on my phone.

Comment: You might be right with that, see e.g. [here](/a/139363/16575). Could also be introduced post-5.0 in general together with that FRP stuff (didn't check there). But we shouldn't further discuss this in the comments here :)

Comment: @Izzy I'm a bit surprised, as one would assume android.stack would know how to make backup using adb, yet still no answer for my question...

Comment: As I wrote: I never use full backups (I don't like to place all my eggs into a single basket). But have you already checked with our [adb tag-wiki](/tags/adb/info), our [backup tag-wiki](/tags/backup/info), and especially with [answered questions using both these tags](/search?q=[backup]+[adb]+answers%3A1)? :) Pointers from the latter: [ADB backup is not working](/q/67735/16575) / [What all does ADB backup and how do I restore part of it?](/q/69567/16575)